# Authenticated user can still create Kubernetes pods despite restrictred PodSecurityPolicy in place

Tags: security, kubernetes

I am trying to get started with `PodSecurityPolicy` on a bare-metal Kubernetes 1.18.3 cluster with user management provided by Keycloak. `psp/restricted` should apply in `namespace/restricted` (both for a specific user `user` and the namespace's `serviceaccount/default`) , and `psp/unrestricted` should apply in `namespace/unrestricted`. I have the basics working (admission controller `PodSecurityPolicy` installed, etc.), and the following resources are in place:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- kind: Role
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: user
    namespace: restricted
  rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
- kind: RoleBinding
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: user
    namespace: restricted
  subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: user
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  roleRef:
    kind: Role
    name: user
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: PodSecurityPolicy
  apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
  kind: PodSecurityPolicy
  metadata:
    name: restricted
  spec:
    privileged: false
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
    - '*'
- kind: PodSecurityPolicy
  apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
  kind: PodSecurityPolicy
  metadata:
    name: unrestricted
  spec:
    privileged: true
    hostNetwork: true
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
    - '*'
- kind: ClusterRole
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: restricted
  rules:
  - apiGroups: ["policy"]
    resources: ["podsecuritypolicies"]
    verbs: ["use"]
    resourceNames:
    - restricted
- kind: ClusterRole
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: unrestricted
  rules:
  - apiGroups: ["policy"]
    resources: ["podsecuritypolicies"]
    verbs: ["use"]
    resourceNames:
    - unrestricted
- kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: restricted
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: restricted
  - kind: User
    name: user
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  roleRef:
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: restricted
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: unrestrictied
  subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: system:nodes
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: unrestricted
  roleRef:
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: unrestricted
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

In terms of `use` permission, everything looks as expected, e.g.:

```
kubectl auth can-i use podsecuritypolicy/restricted --as user --as-group=system:authenticated # yes
kubectl auth can-i use podsecuritypolicy/unrestricted --as user --as-group=system:authenticated # no
```

But what I observe is that while `serviceaccount:restricrted:default` cannot created privileged pods in `namespace/restricted`, user `user` apparently still can (at a time when that user is authenticated to the cluster):

```
kubectl create -f - <<EOF # succeeds (as expected)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: unprivileged-test-pod
  namespace: restricted
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  pause
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
EOF
kubectl create -f - <<EOF # succeeds (unexpected)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: privileged-test-pod
  namespace: restricted
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  pause
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
EOF
```

Both created containers bear an annotation `kubernetes.io/psp: unrestricted`, whereas I would have expected the creation of `pod/unrestricted` for when user `user` is authenticated in to fail. Things work as expected with `kubectl create deployment` (i.e. creation of the restricted unrestrictred deployments both indirectly by `serviceaccount:default` in namespace `restricted` succeed and fail respectively. Somehow the user (but not the service account appears to be bound to a too wide security policy.

What am I missing? How can I further diagnose the and solve the problem (i.e. prevent both `serviceaccount/default` in `namespace/restricted` and user `user` from creating privileged pods in `namespace/restricted`?

**UPDATE** I think I have now isolated to root cause, but do not know a good solution yet. It would appear that `resources: ["*"]`, `verbs: ["*"]` in `role/user` also grants permission to `use` any (cluster-wide) resource `psp`. This is unintended: I want for `role/user` to permit `user` the "usual" activities inside `namespace/restricted`, not let it `use` each and any `psp` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnosis (see **UPDATE**) was correct. The solution consisted in switching from the proprietary `role/user` (with too encompassing permissions `{apiGroups: ["*"], resources: ["*"], verbs: ["*"]}` to the Kubernetes default [`clusterrole/edit`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles) (which specifically excludes `apiGroup`: `"policy"`, `resource`: `"podsecuritypolicy"`, `verb`: `"use"`.

Comment: Did you try to use RoleBinding instead of ClusterRoleBinding? It looks like this is not good practice to grant all privileges to the newly "user".  Could you apply your last working solution just to show community members desired state?

Comment: @Hanx I am using `ClusterRoleBinding` for psps for now. Have not thought through yet what the exact difference would be. Can you spell it out for me? Notice that `role/user` and `rolebinding/user` should confine `user` to `namespace/restricted`. (There was a typo re those roles which I have now corrected.)

Comment: What I can see in your config, 1. You are using Role/Rolebinding but you are not referencing any podsecuritypolicies in apiGroups: ["policy"], 2. In addition for RoleBinding you are referencing  in subjects  - kind: Group  name: user while testing you are using different group: --as-group=system:authenticated

Comment: @Hanx ad 1. IMO my `clusterrole/restricted` and `clusterrole/privileged` do reference the respective `psp`s in `apiGroups: ["policy"]`. (You may have to scroll down the box to encounter that part.) ad 2. IMO it won't work w/o `system:authenticated`, for this is what Kubernetes implicitly adds for any authenticated user. If you want to simulate that situation w/ `kubctl can-i` you have to add it explicitly.